Local coordinates around fixed point under symplectic automorphism of K3 surface
Let $ X $ be a complex algebraic K3 surface (smooth, by definition) and $ f : X \to X $ be a symplectic automorphism of finite order, that is, $ f $ preserves the volume form on $ X $. It is known that $ f $ has isolated fixed points only.
Let $ p \in X $ be an isolated fixed point. Let $ \mathcal{O}_{X,p} $ be the local ring at $ p $ and $ m_p $ the maximal ideal. The automorphism $ f $ induces the usual automorphism $ f^{\#} : \mathcal{O}_{X,p} \to \mathcal{O}_{X,p} $ of local rings.
Is it possible to find a regular sequence $ x,y \in m_p $ such that $ f^{\#}(x) = \mu x $ and $ f^{\#}(y) = \mu^{-1} y $ ? That is, I want to know if I can find a diagonal action on coordinates. It is certainly true on $ m_p / m_p^2 $ but I’m hoping it’s true for $ m_p $ too.

Any automorphism of a complex manifold of finite order can always be linearised in a neighbourhood of a fixed point. I am not sure of the original reference for this, but there should be a reference (or proof) in the article "Local classification of quotients of complex manifolds by discontinuous groups" (Duke Math. J. v. 34) by David Prill.

@naf Thank you for your helpful comment, and the reference. This is exactly what I wanted.
